# Algorithm Optimization -- Automatic Dimensionality of PCA

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x, mathematics

I have implemented (rather, edited the implementation of) a technique to automatically detect the optimal number of dimensions for [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), [based off of this paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2000/file/7503cfacd12053d309b6bed5c89de212-Paper.pdf).

This was inspired by `sklearn`'s implementation of the algorithm described in the paper, [found here in their `_pca.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py) module.

Code, including an example for anyone to use via `sklearn`'s [`make_classification`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_multilabel_classification.html) technique is below:

```
# Borrowed mainly from: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py

import numpy as np, pandas as pd, warnings, numbers
from math import log1p, sqrt
from scipy import linalg
from scipy.special import gammaln
from scipy.sparse import issparse
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from tqdm import tqdm

def infer_dimension(spectrum, n_samples):
    ll = np.empty_like(spectrum)
    ll[0] = -np.inf  # we don't want to return n_components = 0
    for rank in tqdm(range(1, spectrum.shape[0])):
        ll[rank] = assess_dimension(spectrum, rank, n_samples)
    return ll.argmax()

def stable_cumsum(arr, axis=None, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08):
    out = np.cumsum(arr, axis=axis, dtype=np.float64)
    expected = np.sum(arr, axis=axis, dtype=np.float64)

    return out

def assess_dimension(spectrum, rank, n_samples):    
    n_features = spectrum.shape[0]
    if not 1 <= rank < n_features:
        raise ValueError("the tested rank should be in [1, n_features - 1]")

    eps = 1e-15

    if spectrum[rank - 1] < eps:
        return -np.inf

    pu = -rank * log1p(2.)
    for i in range(1, rank + 1):
        pu += (gammaln((n_features - i + 1) / 2.) - log1p(np.pi) * (n_features - i + 1) / 2.)

    pl = np.sum(np.log(spectrum[:rank]))
    pl = -pl * n_samples / 2.

    v = max(eps, np.sum(spectrum[rank:]) / (n_features - rank))
    pv = -np.log1p(v) * n_samples * (n_features - rank) / 2.

    m = n_features * rank - rank * (rank + 1.) / 2.
    pp = log1p(2. * np.pi) * (m + rank) / 2.

    pa = 0.
    spectrum_ = spectrum.copy()
    spectrum_[rank:n_features] = v
    for i in range(rank):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(spectrum)):
            pa += log1p((spectrum[i] - spectrum[j]) *
                      (1. / spectrum_[j] - 1. / spectrum_[i])) + log1p(n_samples)
    
    ll = pu + pl + pv + pp - pa / 2. - rank * log1p(n_samples) / 2.

    return ll    

def find_components(data):
    try:
        X = data.to_numpy()
    except:
        X = data
        warnings.warn('Data is already in numpy format, or cannot be converted', RuntimeWarning)

    n_samples = X.shape[0]

    av = np.mean(data, axis=0)
    X -= av
    print("Calculating S...")
    U, S, Vt = linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
    print("Calculating explained variance...")
    explained_variance_ = (S ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)
    print("Calculating total variance variance...")
    total_var = explained_variance_.sum()
    print("Calculating explained variance ratio...")
    explained_variance_ratio_ = explained_variance_ / total_var

    print("Inferring dimensions...")
    n_components = infer_dimension(explained_variance_, n_samples)

    if 0 < n_components < 1.0:
        print("n_components not complete | Calculating ratio cumsum...")
        ratio_cumsum = stable_cumsum(explained_variance_ratio_)
        n_components = np.searchsorted(ratio_cumsum, n_components,
                                               side='right') + 1

    return n_components

X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=5000, n_classes=2)

n_components = find_components(X)
print(n_components)
```

While this code works well and outputs results properly, it takes an incredibly long time to process large datasets. The dataset in particular that I am using is an [`NLP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) dataset, particularly of `term frequency` values, so there are a LOT of zeroes and the data does not follow a normal distribution (not a single feature does) (not sure if that makes a difference). My dataset's size is `(550683, 10891)`. That is estimated to take more than 10 days to finish on my current hardware.

How can I optimize this code to improve performance? Using the `make_multilabel_classification` call above, even that takes a fair amount of time given the feature space. .

Please note, if you believe the algorithm was implemented incorrectly please feel free to fix that. Principally concerned with speed

Comment: Can you share a benchmark test (perhaps a subset of the real target data?) that we could easily replicate on our own machines?

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter sure, running now. However, you could simply run the code I have now, vs your optimized code, on your own machine to demonstrate improvement. That way hardware differences between your machine and mine are not factored into play.

Answer (score 1):

### Test harness:

To build a modular test rig around this, it seemed easiest to wrap stuff up in a class. I'm pretty sure I left everything else in the original implementation alone.

I'm just using `time` to measure how long the function takes with various input values. I'm too impatient to run it with your original parameters, so I'm mostly using smaller ones. **I have basically no idea what your code actually does, so it's possible I'm doing something wrong in how I test it.**

### Cleanup:

This is fairly opinionated, and
<s>may not actually help with performance</s>
<s>actually made the function a little slower</s>
<s>each individual change is as likely to hurt performance as to help</s>
only helps performance by ~10%.

- I greatly prefer to use python built-ins over numpy/scipy etc for data-structure manipulation.
- Why is `stable_cumsum` a function? It looks like you had an assertion in there or something that got removed...
- Your variable names are pretty opaque. Without domain knowledge, I can't do much to fix this. You're also reassigning variables more than necessary, which is good to avoid.
- I golfed the math a little and I think it reads better.

### Math:

The algorithm seams to be O(n^3). `calculate_pa` is (presumably) the bottleneck. What can we do to simplify it?

- We can pull the `+ log1p(self.n_samples)` term outside the `sum`, and just use multiplication.
- A sum of logs is a log of the product, and `log1p` is just "ln(x+1)", so we can move the log calculation outside the aggregation.
- **But then I think we're stuck.** The calculation doesn't actually work in this form because of a math-overflow error, and I haven't actually figured out any *fundamental* simplification that would touch the complexity-class.
- **Your domain knowledge may be able to push this forward.** In particular, I noticed that I could get it to work for *very small* tests by just omitting the `+1` from the product-term. It looks like the exact math in that area doesn't really matter too much; maybe there's a lighter-weight calculation you could be maximizing?

### Code:

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, warnings, numbers
from math import log1p, sqrt
from scipy import linalg
from scipy.special import gammaln
from scipy.sparse import issparse
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from tqdm import tqdm

from random import randint  # insecure RNG is fine for this task.
from time import time
from operator import itemgetter, mul
from functools import reduce
from math import log

class Original:
    def __init__(self, verbose):
        self.verbose = verbose

    def log(self, *message):
        if self.verbose:
            print(*message)

    def infer_dimension(self, spectrum, n_samples):
        ll = np.empty_like(spectrum)
        ll[0] = -np.inf  # we don't want to return n_components = 0
        for rank in (tqdm(range(1, spectrum.shape[0]))
                     if self.verbose else range(1, spectrum.shape[0])):
            ll[rank] = self.assess_dimension(spectrum, rank, n_samples)
        return ll.argmax()

    def stable_cumsum(self, arr, axis=None, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08):
        out = np.cumsum(arr, axis=axis, dtype=np.float64)
        expected = np.sum(arr, axis=axis, dtype=np.float64)
        return out

    def assess_dimension(self, spectrum, rank, n_samples):    
        n_features = spectrum.shape[0]
        if not 1 <= rank < n_features:
            raise ValueError("the tested rank should be in [1, n_features - 1]")
        eps = 1e-15

        if spectrum[rank - 1] < eps:
            return -np.inf

        pu = -rank * log1p(2.)
        for i in range(1, rank + 1):
            pu += (gammaln((n_features - i + 1) / 2.) - log1p(np.pi) * (n_features - i + 1) / 2.)

        pl = np.sum(np.log(spectrum[:rank]))
        pl = -pl * n_samples / 2.

        v = max(eps, np.sum(spectrum[rank:]) / (n_features - rank))
        pv = -np.log1p(v) * n_samples * (n_features - rank) / 2.

        m = n_features * rank - rank * (rank + 1.) / 2.
        pp = log1p(2. * np.pi) * (m + rank) / 2.

        pa = 0.
        spectrum_ = spectrum.copy()
        spectrum_[rank:n_features] = v
        for i in range(rank):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(spectrum)):
                pa += log1p((spectrum[i] - spectrum[j]) *
                          (1. / spectrum_[j] - 1. / spectrum_[i])) + log1p(n_samples)
        
        ll = pu + pl + pv + pp - pa / 2. - rank * log1p(n_samples) / 2.

        return ll    

    def find_components(self, data):
        try:
            X = data.to_numpy()
        except:
            X = data
            self.log('Data is already in numpy format, or cannot be converted')

        n_samples = X.shape[0]

        av = np.mean(data, axis=0)
        X -= av
        self.log("Calculating S...")
        U, S, Vt = linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
        self.log("Calculating explained variance...")
        explained_variance_ = (S ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)
        self.log("Calculating total variance variance...")
        total_var = explained_variance_.sum()
        self.log("Calculating explained variance ratio...")
        explained_variance_ratio_ = explained_variance_ / total_var

        self.log("Inferring dimensions...")
        n_components = self.infer_dimension(explained_variance_, n_samples)

        if 0 < n_components < 1.0:
            self.log("n_components not complete | Calculating ratio cumsum...")
            ratio_cumsum = self.stable_cumsum(explained_variance_ratio_)
            n_components = np.searchsorted(ratio_cumsum, n_components,
                                                   side='right') + 1

        return n_components

class Cleaned:
    def __init__(self, verbose):
        self.verbose = verbose

    def log(self, *message):
        if self.verbose:
            print(*message)

    def infer_dimension(self):
        return max(
            range(1, self.spectrum.shape[0]),
            key=self.assess_dimension,
            default=0
        )

    def stable_cumsum(self, arr, axis=None):
        # Why is this broken out at all? 
        return np.cumsum(arr, axis=axis, dtype=np.float64)

    def assess_dimension(self, rank):    
        assert 1 <= rank < self.n_features, "the tested rank should be in [1, n_features - 1]"

        epsilon = 1e-15
        if self.spectrum[rank - 1] < epsilon:
            return -np.inf
        else:
            pu = (-rank * log1p(2.)) + sum(
                gammaln((self.n_features - i + 1) / 2.) - log1p(np.pi) * (self.n_features - i + 1) / 2.
                for i in range(1, rank + 1)
            )
            pl = -np.sum(np.log(self.spectrum[:rank])) * self.n_samples / 2.

            v = max(epsilon, np.sum(self.spectrum[rank:]) / (self.n_features - rank))
            pv = -np.log1p(v) * self.n_samples * (self.n_features - rank) / 2.

            m = self.n_features * rank - rank * (rank + 1.) / 2.
            pp = log1p(2. * np.pi) * (m + rank) / 2.

            pa = self.calculate_pa(rank, v)

            return pu + pl + pv + pp - pa / 2. - rank * log1p(self.n_samples) / 2.

    def calculate_pa(self, rank, v):
        _spectrum = self.spectrum.copy()
        _spectrum[rank:self.n_features] = v
        i_spectrum = 1. / _spectrum
        return sum(
            log1p(
                (self.spectrum[i] - self.spectrum[j]) * (i_spectrum[j] - i_spectrum[i])
            ) + log1p(self.n_samples)
            for i in range(rank)
            for j in range(i + 1, self.n_features)
        )

    def find_components(self, X):
        self.n_samples = X.shape[0]
        centered = X - np.mean(X, axis=0)
        U, S, Vt = linalg.svd(centered, full_matrices=False)
        self.spectrum = (S ** 2) / (self.n_samples - 1)
        self.n_features = self.spectrum.shape[0]
        n_components = self.infer_dimension()

        if 0 < n_components < 1.0:
            explained_variance_ratio = self.spectrum / self.spectrum.sum()
            ratio_cumsum = self.stable_cumsum(explained_variance_ratio)
            return np.searchsorted(ratio_cumsum, n_components, side='right') + 1
        else:
            return n_components

class Optimized(Cleaned):
    def calculate_pa(self, rank, v):
        _spectrum = self.spectrum.copy()
        _spectrum[rank:self.n_features] = v
        i_spectrum = 1. / _spectrum
        number_of_terms = -0.5 * rank * (rank - (2 * len(self.spectrum)) + 1)  # https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28sum%281+for+j+from+i+%2B+1+to+s+-+1%29+for+i+from+0+to+r+-+1%29
        constant_part = log1p(self.n_samples) * number_of_terms
        # This commented-out block 
        return log(reduce(mul, (
            ((self.spectrum[i] - self.spectrum[j]) * (i_spectrum[j] - i_spectrum[i]))
            for i in range(rank)
            for j in range(i + 1, self.n_features)
        ))) + constant_part
        #return sum(
        #    log(
        #       1 + ((self.spectrum[i] - self.spectrum[j]) * (i_spectrum[j] - i_spectrum[i]))
        #    )
        #    for i in range(rank)
        #    for j in range(i + 1, self.n_features)
        #) + constant_part

def make_test(samples, features, classes):
    X, _ = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=samples, n_features=features, n_classes=classes)
    return (samples, features, classes, X, None)

def time_function(f, *args, post_process=lambda x: x):
    start = time()
    retval = f(*args)
    end = time()
    return post_process(retval), end - start

def print_row(*args):
    strings = [f'{a:^12}' if isinstance(a, str) else (f'{a:>12}' if isinstance(a, int) else f'{a:>12.6}')
               for a in args]
    print('|'.join(strings))

def main():
    candidates = {
        "Original": Original(False).find_components,
        "Cleaned": Cleaned(False).find_components,
        "Optimized": Optimized(False).find_components,
    }
    tests = [
        make_test(100, 50, 2),
        make_test(1000, 500, 2),
    ]
    print_row('samples', 'features', 'classes', *candidates.keys(), 'answer')
    for samples, features, classes, data, known in tests:
        results = [time_function(f, data.copy(), post_process=int)
                   for f in candidates.values()]
        answers = [
            answer
            for answer in [known, *(r[0] for r in results)]
            if answer is not None
        ]
        assert 1 == len(set(answers)), f'1 != len({"; ".join(map(str, answers))})'
        print_row(samples, features, classes, *(r[1] for r in results), results[0][0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
  samples   |  features  |  classes   |  Original  |  Cleaned   | Optimized  |   answer
         100|          50|           2|    0.166063|    0.153894|    0.151417|          49
SO_254392.py:185: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  return log(reduce(mul, (
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SO_254392.py", line 236, in <module>
    main()
  File "SO_254392.py", line 232, in main
    assert 1 == len(set(answers)), f'1 != len({"; ".join(map(str, answers))})'
AssertionError: 1 != len(499; 499; 1)
```

or, if we cut out the failed optimization path:

```
  samples   |  features  |  classes   |  Original  |  Cleaned   |   answer
         100|          50|           2|    0.161394|    0.154552|          49
        1000|         500|           2|     44.1136|     35.9878|         499
```